# Preloader doesn't stop on mobile devices - wordpress

Tags: wordpress

after I’ve been looking for a similar question to solve my issue, which was unsuccessful, I am now addressing to the community for help!

On my portfolio-website https://www.signz-fiction.at (umbrella quantum template) there is a preloader which doesn’t go away on mobile devices after you refresh the page (or press the green logo on top).

Although it is not an optimal solution for me i tried to disable the preloader under custom css but this did not work either

#preloader{display:none !important;}

Or

body > .preloader{ display: none; }

Though I am ui designer, I have only basic knowledge in web development and so I don't know how to fix the problem.

Grateful for any help, thx!

Ps:
The website is a bit older and there was a problem with the google font when i switched from http to https.
Could it be that the prealoder-thing is also related to the switch?

Comment: If you have a small amount of knowledge on how to include a script, I've made a simple loader similar to yours not so long ago, here is the repo https://github.com/amarinediary/Vanilla-JS-Pages-Transition-Loader. It's a simple, lightweight one liner js script. You should able to replace your default one with mine. In any case, when your problem is theme specific, you should adress to your theme support.

Comment: ok thank u, I must see if I can integrate this one. I have contacted the support, but they didn't answer, probably because my support option for this theme has expired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be confusing the loader animation with a preloader (which pre loads images and other assets to make them readily available).

On your site, the loader animation element has the class `.loader`, I've looked at your site with View-Source and haven't seen any element with the `.preloader` class

Try:

```
body .loader  {
display: none;
}
```

but note that this might not help because the loader is controlled by JavaScript which might remove this property on page load.

Also, you have errors on your site:

1. mixed active content - avoid using `http://` on your `https://` site
2. a JS error you should look at, that may be the reason why the loader isn't being removed on time

Comment: I haven't expected an answer that fast and it also worked.

Comment: You are a genius!

Comment: the command takes effect and the prealoader can be deactivated with it

and thanks for the further hints, i will probably hire a developer for this.

Comment: Happy to help! Welcome to StackOverflow :) If the answer worked for you, please mark it as the correct answer to help future visitors who stumble upon this question. Good luck!